# PHP Header won't pass variables

Tags: php, variables, header

I've been trying this

```
header('location:view.php?id='.$editid.'&catid='.$catid.'');
exit;
```

and it will only pass the $editid variable, the second one just comes blank so the URL looks like

```
 view.php?id=0&catid=
```

I use almost the exact same thing on a different page and it works flawlessly, and both variables are defined. On another page, I use an identical header and neither variable is passed.

Variables are defined. Catid is defined as

```
$catid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, strip_tags($_REQUEST["catid"]));
```

Edit: Full script:

```
if($mygroup == "admin" or $mygroup == "moderator"){
$editid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, strip_tags($_REQUEST["id"]));
$catid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, strip_tags($_REQUEST["catid"]));
if(isset($_POST['title'])){
    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, strip_tags($_POST['title']));
    if($mygroup == "admin"){
        $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, ($_POST['content']));
    }
    else{
        $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, strip_tags($_POST['content']));
    }
    $query = "UPDATE threads SET title = '$title', content = '$content' WHERE `id` = '$editid'"
    or die("Query failed");
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    header("Location: view.php?id=".$editid."&catid=".$catid);
    exit;
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    }
```

}

Comment: Well, at that point `$catid` is not set to anything, or is set to a blank string. You need to do some basic debugging. This code shows us nothing. Also doing `.''` at the end of a string is the same as adding `+0` to the end of all mathematical equations. Stop that.

Comment: Are you rewriting something? the var name isn't id= ? the urls seems different.

Comment: _I use almost the exact same thing_ - "almost" isn't "exact" :-)

Comment: How about showing us the source of those variables?

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on both those variables - just above the `header()`, and paste results please.

Comment: `$catid` may be defined as the result of a query, but if the query returns nothing, `$catid` will be nothing.

Comment: Updated to show how the variable is defined, and checking if it was defined was the first thing I did. Almost as in the only thing that changes is the name of the variable.

Comment: Its a data issue, this code is fine.

Comment: And yes $catid is sent, I can echo it.

Comment: var dump on catid gives me string(2) "31"

Comment: disable your header line and try echo $editid." last ".$catid; what is the output of this line?

Comment: Are you sure `$catid` is defined with that value before you call `header()`?

Comment: If I echo $catid and $editid it outputs 31 52 which is what it should be, but when I try to use them with the header only editid will pass

Comment: If what you are saying is true, then you should get the `$catid` concatenated to the string [**as shown here**](http://ideone.com/skzzzL).

Comment: @crush that works perfectly and echo's the id's that it should, but still no luck with the header.

Comment: @user3010610 That doesn't make any sense. I think you're going to have to show us the entire script for anyone to figure this out.

Comment: @crush updated and posted the full script.

Comment: Just a note. You're using double quotes for your string. You could do the following: `header("Location: view.php?id=$editid&catid=$catid");` also, that `mysqli_close` is never getting executed because you kill the script right before it.

Comment: I don't see anything that should be causing the behavior you describe though. If you have truly tried checking the value of `$catid` on the line just before where you send the `header()` and commenting out the `header()` line, and it echos out the value you expect, then I'm at a complete loss for why this could/would happen.

Comment: Thanks, changed that and I've moved the mysqli_close. Still only passing the $editid variable, which is strange because $catid is set.

Comment: Off topic: `mysqli_close($dbc);` after `exit;` won't execute;

Answer (score 0):

```
$editid=0;$catid=1;
header('location:test.php?id='.$editid.'&catid='.$catid.'');
exit;
```

Is working for me. Are you sure $catid is set?
Try to debug :

```
echo 'location:test.php?id='.$editid.'&catid='.$catid;
exit;
```

Comment: $catid is %100 set. I did var_dump on $catid and get string(2) "31" but it still won't pass the $catid variable.